# Get specific field from a site page via Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I get all my sites via:

```
$pages = Get-PnPListItem -List Sites
```

I use the variable and get to every site in a foreach-loop:

```
foreach($page in $pages)
  {
Write-Host "Page" $page.FieldValues["FileLeafRef"] "..."

 }
```

Above will print out the name for every page. Let say that the page come from a library/list that have the column "category". How can I access the value from that column in the foreach-loop?

Comment: Do you have the ID of your page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as below  your prpoerty should be as $($myData) in your string

```
Write-Host "Page '$($page.FieldValues["FileLeafRef"])' '$($page.FieldValues["category"])'   "
```

Answer (score 1):

try below code, Id 47 is the Item Id in the library

```
Connect-PnPOnline –Url https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/dev –Credentials (Get-Credential)
$item = Get-PnPListItem -List "Site Pages" -Id 47

$Fields = Get-PnPField -List "Site Pages"

foreach($Field in $Fields)
 {
        Write-Host $Field.InternalName -ForegroundColor Yellow
        Write-Host $item[$Field.InternalName]
  }
```

[Source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/8d1f812b-4c8f-4850-8e66-66d8bf8f0355/powershell-to-show-all-page-properties?forum=onlineservicessharepoint)